# Capture Windows shutdown, log off and restart in Windows service built in Java?

Tags: java, winapi

Is there a way to catch a Windows log off or/and shutdown event in a Windows service built in Java?

I want to capture windows event in a Windows service and after capturing I want to send an mail.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that you have a pure Java solution here.

I can see two ways.

You can run your process as a Windows service. So, you can assume that if it is going down it happens together with the OS shutting down the process. It is not 100% correct but relatively simple.

Another way is to find some process that starts when the OS is going down and try to perform polling on processes. Alternatively you can probably use [WMI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Management_Instrumentation) events. To connect to WMI from Java you can use one of: [JaWin](http://jawinproject.sourceforge.net/), [J-integra](http://j-integra.intrinsyc.com/com.asp), [J-interop](http://j-interop.sourceforge.net/) or create your own WMI script in VBScript or JScript and run it from Java using CScript.

Answer (score 0):

You can be notified in regular usermode code via WM_QUERYENDSESSION. However you'll need to use JNI and create a window with which you associate a WndProc to receive this message.