# Capture JFrame shutdown when windows is forced shutdown and log it

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, shutdown

I have a gui running. If windows is forced restarted I want my gui to log this right before it shuts down. I'm using the following code, it works when you click on "X" to shut the window down, but does not work if it is forced shutdown by windows.

```
WindowAdapter listener = new WindowAdapter() {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent w) {  
        log(w.paramString());
        frame.dispose();
        }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use the `Runtime.addShutdownHook(...)` method.

The Java virtual machine shuts down in response to two kinds of events:

1. The program exits normally, when the last non-daemon thread exits or when the exit (equivalently, System.exit) method is invoked, or
2. The virtual machine is terminated in response to a user interrupt, such as typing ^C, or a system-wide event, such as user logoff or system shutdown.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like you can catch an OS Restart event.  However, there are some other suggestions here which may help you:  [Capture Windows shutdown, log off and restart in Windows service built in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6897882/capture-windows-shutdown-log-off-and-restart-in-windows-service-built-in-java)